# bundling failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input in react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, npm, firebase-authentication

i am using **firebase** in my **react native project**. when i am try to sign up user with email and password this error is comming.
i am using **window OS** and only **andorid render**

**Note:**  i had read all questions related to this but nothing helped

**newbiew** to react native .please guide in proper way

**package.json**

```
"firebase": "^5.8.2",
    "native-base": "^2.11.0",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "^0.57.8",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.2.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.15",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.23.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^8.0.10",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.2.1"
```

**Code for sign up**

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'

//Intiazlize firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCUK5QkcvTcvfCKlbwnnI8GskIgcLGMcqA",
    authDomain: "trailertracker-da09c.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://trailertracker-da09c.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "trailertracker-da09c",
    storageBucket: "",
}


firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

 signUpUser = (email,password) => {
        try{
            if(this.state.password.length < 6 ){
                alert("Please Enter Valid Email and Password")
                return
            }

            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)

        } catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
```

Complete error is

> Loading dependency graph, done. error: bundling failed: SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected end of JSON input
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at FileStore.get (F:\React Native\ReactProjects\trailer-tracker\TrailerTracker\node_modules\metro-cache\src\stores\FileStore.js:26:19)
>       at F:\React Native\ReactProjects\trailer-tracker\TrailerTracker\node_modules\metro-cache\src\Cache.js:76:40
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at step (F:\React Native\ReactProjects\trailer-tracker\TrailerTracker\node_modules\metro-cache\src\Cache.js:18:30)
>       at F:\React Native\ReactProjects\trailer-tracker\TrailerTracker\node_modules\metro-cache\src\Cache.js:37:14
>       at new Promise ()
>       at F:\React Native\ReactProjects\trailer-tracker\TrailerTracker\node_modules\metro-cache\src\Cache.js:15:12
>       at Cache.get (F:\React Native\ReactProjects\trailer-tracker\TrailerTracker\node_modules\metro-cache\src\Cache.js:102:7)
>       at F:\React Native\ReactProjects\trailer-tracker\TrailerTracker\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Transformer.js:166:34
>   BUNDLE  [android, dev] ....../index.js 68.2% (947/1147), failed.

is this another error or error in firebase ?

Help will be highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Is that the exact content of your *package.json* fiile? If it is then just try to surround it in curly braces. The whole file must be a valid JSON object.

Comment: no its just part of pacage.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get started with firebase in react native.

add firebase dependency

```
yarn add firebase
```

> Goto **Firebase** and make a new project and going to the section
>   **Add Firebase to your web app**

Make a class for configation of Firebase like this

```
import firebase from "@firebase/app";
require("firebase/database");
require("firebase/storage");
require("firebase/auth");

let config = {
  apiKey: "YOUR PROJECT apiKey",
  authDomain: "YOUR PROJECT authDomain",
  databaseURL: "YOUR PROJECT databaseURL",
  projectId: "XXXXXXXX",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXX",
  appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
};

export default class DBHandler {
  static auth;
  static database;

  static init() {
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    DBHandler.database = firebase.database();
    DBHandler.auth = firebase.auth();
  }
}
```

in **App.js** initialize Firebase

```
import DBHanlder from "./src/api/constants";

export default class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount = () => {

    DBHanlder.init();
  };

  render() {
    return <YourApp />;
  }
}
```

> Your're done with initialization part .now you can use for **auth** like below

```
import DBHandler from "../api/constants";
class Login extends Component {

signinUser = () => {
DBHandler.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(() => {
          //Do what you want
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          //handle error
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          alert(errorMessage);
          console.log("ERROR");
          console.log(errorCode, errorMessage);
        });
    }
}}
```